# XSL unescape preprocessing

Tags: xml, xslt

I've an input XML document that is partially encoded. Here's a sample :

```
<content>
  <body>
    &lt;div class="contentLayout"&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;table&gt;
      [table's content]
    &lt;/table&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  </body>
</content>
```

With the help of an XSL stylesheet, I'd like to display the table's content only, but don't know how to deal with the escaped code.
I thought first to unescape then select `<table>` node, but I've found no way to do this.
Using `<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />` seems good, but it doesn't let me select the `<table>` node only.

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format markup as code so that it displays properly.  Thanks.

Comment: Done. Thanks in advance

Comment: Good start.  Keep going.  You're not done.

Comment: Ok, I think it's good now.
That's my first question on stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: @PierreG What tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using an XSL stylesheet. I've edited my question to clarify this point.

Comment: I meant what tool are you using to execute the XSL transformation.

Comment: The XSL transformation is done by Confluence XSLT macro : https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/HTML/XSLT+Macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The XSL transformation is done by Confluence XSLT macro

I'm afraid I am not familiar with the tool. If you can, I would suggest you do this in two passes: first, use `disable-output-escaping` on the `body` element, and save the result to a new file. Then process the new file in the second pass.

The alternative is ugly and can easily lead to unexpected results:

```
<xsl:template match="/content">
    <table>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(body, '&lt;table&gt;'), '&lt;/table&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks.
Is it possible to save the first pass in a variable, instead of a new physical file ?

Comment: @PierreG No, it's not. You need to have the processor serialize the result, and that will only happen on the final output.